# Manipulating an Image Dynamicly based on time and database details

Tags: java, php, image-manipulation

I have a JPEG image, which consists of one floor of a building containing various rooms. Based on data retrieved from an SQL database through PHP, and the current time of the day, I wish to manipulate the rooms within the image to change colour based on time of the day and whether or not the room is currently in use(a boolean check from the database for example will be used to achieve this). Access to the database must be performed through PHP. The platform for this will be through a website.

What technologies, libraries or otherwise can anyone suggest I can use to achieve this. I have never performed anything such as image manipulation before so I am in seek of guidance. The first task I must deal with is separating each room on the image some how. A solution through the use of Java would be preferred.

Any advice is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's GD extension is what you are looking for.  GD2 is standard these days.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

I use this library all the time - there are lots of good functions.  Happy manipulation!